# Losing $_SESSION variable across pages

Tags: php, session

I come to you absolutely frustrated. I spent days looking through my code and the entire StackOverflow questions looking for the following issue:

The function of my project is to log in using three pages. 
***The first page*** `1.php` has the input fields to be filled up:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

require_once "init.php";
require "header.php";

?>

<form method="POST" action="2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
     <tr><td>Username</td></tr>
     <tr><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value=""/></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Password</td></tr>
     <tr><td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value=""/></td></tr>
     <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Get in"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

***The second page*** `2.php` processes the info, checks if the user and password are correct, and initializes `$_SESSION['user']`;

```
<?php
session_start();
session_save_path('/server/path/system/sphp');
//had to change dir due to server restrictions

$username= $_POST['user'];
$user= "cpe12";
$userpass= $_POST['pass'];
$pass= "p2010";

    if($username==$user&&$userpass==$pass){

    $_SESSION['user']= $username;
    echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=3.php'>Loging </head>";
    echo $_SESSION['user'];
    exit();
    }
       elseif ($username!=$user||$userpass!=$pass){
            session_destroy();    
            echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=1.php'>Wrong log in</head>";
            exit();

            } 

?>
```

And I protect ***the third page*** `3.php` content using an `isset` function.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_save_path('/server/path/system/sphp');
//I know I could use an include_once instead of these two lines, right?

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){

             $title= "Copies";
             require "header.php";
             require "content.php";

          }
                else{
                    session_destroy();
                    echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='4; url=index.php'>Blocked content.</head>";
                    die();

                }
?>
```

Whenever I try to log in it validates ok in `2.php` but when it gets to `3.php` it fails to login. All pages have session_start and session.save_path written as the first two lines with no blank spaces.
I have changed the default folder `/tmp` for `session.save_path` to `server/path` because `/tmp` had no writing permissions.

I could retrieve some info from `2.php` and appears that `$_SESSION['user']` comes out OK from it, but `3.php` never reads it. The thing is that I have another 6 pages in common to access under this session, so I need a global solution.

Oh, and this is confusing: I also created a file in order to check session information (just for information) named `check.php` with the following code :

```
<?php

   session_start();
   session_save_path('/server/path/system/sphp');

   echo session_save_path().'<br/>';
   echo $_SESSION['user'].'<br/>';
   echo session_name();

   if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
   }

   ?>
```

Now, if I first clear browser history and data and then type `www.myweb.com/check.php` into the URL I see missing info, since `$_SESSION['user']`, etc. haven't been created yet. If afterwards I try to log in, amazingly starts to sign in like a charm, no matter what. SO first I have to access `check.php` on my browser to be able to log in. But if I clear browser history and data again, it doesn't let me log in anymore.

error_reporting on 3.php states:
`Notice: Undefined index: user in "/server/path/system/3.php in line 34`

Might this be something about my server? Something about `save_handlers`? 
This is my first log in, and I went through hell. I think is going to be a long way.
I've no more options or knowledge to apply. You are my last resort.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This never happend in my life before. I copied the code from 2.php and pasted it in another file, which a named try.php (exact same code). I redirected 1.php to check in try.php and then redirect to 3.php. It worked.
Now, I don´t get what could possibly be fixed by coping the exact same code to another file (I literally checked line by line), so I'm very confused. 
But well, works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

**session_save_path()** needs to be called before **session_start()**.

**Refer :** 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

So

```
session_save_path('/server/path/system/sphp');
session_start();
```

Comment: My boss asked a question delaying me. You beat me to it. Upvotes to you my dear sir.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I've already tried that, but I have the same problem. I also created a php.ini but same thing.

Comment: Server problem? I realy don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MarcGamboa can you be specific... what error or what problem you are facing.. because i run the code which you posted ... after changing the `session_save_path('/server/path/system/sphp');
session_start();` its running well... i see no error..

Comment: does this path `/server/path/system/sphp` is able to access...check it well

Comment: @BharathiRaja The main problem was that the code wouldn't let me get into 3.php, it was kicking me back to 1.php. I was so frustrated that yesterday I copied the code from 2.php into a new file which I named try.php, so 1.php would go to try.php to check log in info and access 3.php and it worked. So maybe you can tell me how is that possible. I really don't get how doing that could possibly fix a problem. Thanks for the help anyway, I really appreciate it.